# How can I customize my FTP's "web browser"

Tags: css, user-interface, web, bootstrap-4, ftp

I've just setup my FTP server with vsftpd and i was wondering if i could add a bit of css or bootstrap to the web page generated by the ftp server.

This is for a new Linux server running Debian 9 and vsftpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. How listing on an ftp server gets rendered is fully up to the browser.